# How to implement bullet time in Box2d?

Tags: box2d, openframeworks

I want to implement some sort of bullet time for my box2d app, googling around I found a post were they suggest to change the timestep (something like from 1/30 to 1/60) but its quickly flagged as bad practice, all I need is a basic on/off trigger for the slow motion, any ideas?

Comment: The simulation is less accurate, I think aabb calculation would be wrong for a few timesteps and could allow tunneling of even bullet bodies, and also maybe things like the warm starting would get a bit messed up. But for Ricardo's case it may just be fine, I'd say give it a go and worry about any problems if they actually show up.

Comment: Cool I will give it a try and see what happens thanks

Comment: Well, technically for bullet time the time step would be made *shorter* and therefore calculations would become *more* accurate, but the point is, the behavior of everything will change (sometimes subtly and sometimes conspicuously) because by changing the time step you are changing the nature of the simulation. It's like changing the speed of light of the entire universe. It will #*$& things up. Unless, of course, that is what you're going for.

Answer (score 0):

As of [Box2D 2.0+](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html) altering the time step doesn't negatively impact the simulation so simply use a smaller time step.

Comment: Works in a pinch. Throws determinism out of the window and into a lava pit.

Answer (score 0):

This would be done by changing the timestep.

Changing the timestep will change the simulation slightly, and make it less deterministic.

Whether that's acceptable depends on how essential it is that your physics simulation is deterministic.

If it's a single player game and not a hardcore game you probably don't need to worry about it.

I'm using bullet time in a single player iOS shooter and it's fine. The universe doesn't collapse.